# MS-SQL content-aware unique constraint for multiple columns possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, schema, unique-constraint

I'm building process engine and want to ensure only single process instance is pending or active at given time for the given case. However, identical process can be started once previous instance finishes. I would like to use database constraint for maximum reliability with unrealiable networks and lost responses.

I have table with following columns

- process_id (PRIMARY KEY)
- case_id (FOREIGN KEY)
- state (PENDING | ACTIVE | COMPLETED)

Multiple rows with same case_id and state COMPLETED is allowed for restarts. However, I would like to prevent identical rows with state PENDING or ACTIVE to enforce my requirement of single process instance at time.

Here is example of allowed scenario with identical cases having state COMPLETED

```
process_id    case_id    state
------------------------------
1             1          COMPLETED
2             1          COMPLETED <-- case_id duplicate allowed for multiple COMPLETED
3             1          PENDING
```

Here is example of disallowed scenario with identical cases having state PENDING

```
process_id    case_id    state
------------------------------
1             1          COMPLETED
2             1          COMPLETED
3             1          PENDING
4             1          PENDING   <-- case_id duplicate not allowed for multiple PENDING!
```

And here is example of disallowed scenario with identical cases having combination of states PENDING and ACTIVE

```
process_id    case_id    state
------------------------------
1             1          COMPLETED
2             1          COMPLETED
3             1          ACTIVE
4             1          PENDING   <-- case_id duplicate not allowed for combination of ACTIVE and PENDING!
```

Is this kind of content-aware unique constraint possible in MS-SQL?

Comment: I *suspect* what you want is a filtered `UNIQUE` `INDEX`. Some meaningful (and consumable) sample data, along with the behaviour you are after for certain `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements, will help us understand your goals here.

Comment: While index is good, i think you need to have some sort of "lock" to avoid this kind of issue inside your engine itself. It's much more lightweight to check a, i dunno, a keyed Map in java, then to go all the way to database and parse out the potential exceptions from your process table

Comment: Simple in-memory lock does not work for distributed engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample, it seems that you just need a filtered `UNIQUE` `INDEX` on `case_id` where `state` does not have a value of `'COMPLETED'`:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_IncompleteCases ON dbo.YourTable (cast_id)
WHERE state != 'COMPLETED';
```

This will allow any number of rows, for a single `case_id`, where `state` value has `'COMPLETED'` but will only allow *one* for a single `case_id` for all other values of `state`.

*Note that if `state` is `NULL`able, you may need to add logic to include/exclude those in the above `WHERE`.*